# Problems with listening for an event in child object in Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I have two classes. The first one (the starting class):

```
package
{
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
 import tetris.*;

 public class TetrisGame extends Sprite
 {

  private var _gameWell:Well;

  public function TetrisGame()
  {    
   _gameWell = new Well();
   addChild(_gameWell);
  } 
 }
}
```

The second:

```
package tetris
{
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

 public class Well extends Sprite
 {

  public function Well()
  {
   super();

   addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboard);
  }

  private function onKeyboard(event:KeyboardEvent):void
  {
   //some code is here
  }


 }
}
```

But when I press any buttons on my keyboard, the child class `Well` doesn't have any reaction. What's the problem?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in onKeyboard, does it get triggered?

Comment: If you put a trace statement inside onKeyboard does that ever get written to the output panel?

Comment: One thing to note about event listeners: they're strongly-referenced. If you GC the object holding the event listener (in this case, the "Well" object, the listener will persist, causing a memory leak. There are times to use strong-types (I've noticed a need for this when opening/closing dialogs w/event listeners), but if you can, try using this: `addEventListener(<Event type>, <function>, false, 0, true);` This preserves the default values for "useCapture" and "priority", but sets the "useWeakReference" property to "true". When "Well" is GC'd, the event listener will be also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or as an alternative; add the event listener to the stage, so it doesn't depend on the Well having focus.

```
package tetris
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    public class Well extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Well():void 
        {
            super();

            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyboard);
        }

        private function onKeyboard(event:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            //some code is here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, I get it! =))

I should set focus on the child sprite so it can listen for keyboard events.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import tetris.*;

    public class TetrisGame extends Sprite
    {

        private var _gameWell:Well;

        public function TetrisGame()
        {    
            _gameWell = new Well();
            addChild(_gameWell);

            stage.focus = _gameWell;
        } 
    }
```

}